# LLVM outputs differently than it should

Tags: c, llvm

I am pretty new to using LLVM C API, and never have encountered this issue before. From examples, I seen online when they create a `LLVMTypeRef` using `LLVMIntTypeInContext` and then `LLVMPointerType`, they get a clean `i16*` type, but I get `ptr`
here is the reference code

```c
LLVMTypeRef type = LLVMIntTypeInContext(context,16)
type = LLVMPointerType(type,0)
```

afterwards I just print the module.
I am using MacOs with M1 chip and LLVM version 16.0.6

Some people recommended me install the newer version of LLVM because before that I used version 15, nothing has changed. Then I tried to completely reinstall which changed nothing. I also tried to completely deleting it from my Mac and then install it. Nothing has worked. Can anyone please help me with my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LLVM replaced all pointer types containing pointee type with an opaque pointer type. That pointer type is represented as `ptr`

> The opaque pointer mode can be disabled using -opaque-pointers=0 in LLVM tools like opt, or -Xclang -no-opaque-pointers in clang

For more info, check:
https://llvm.org/docs/OpaquePointers.html

Comment: so it is normal for me to have `ptr` instead of `i8*`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Thank you so much, by any chance could you please tell me why might `LLVMGetFunctionAddress` not work even if the LLVM IR is perfect and LLVMCreateExecutionEngineForModule doesn't spit out any errors?

Comment: Can you ask different question and provide code snippet?